# Find Matching Value Between a Particular Column In Grid View And Tab Panel's Header Text In Tab Container

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel, tabcontainer

does anyone know how could I check if any values from a particular column in the grid view match with any tab panel's header text from the tab container. Let's say if there is 5 columns in the grid view and I just want to look into the values from the 'Product' column, I want to check whether there is matching values between the values from the 'Product' column and all tab panels' header text. All tab panels' header text is distinct from each other. If there is matching values, then the row from the grid view that has matching value will be added to the tab panel that has the same value as its header text.

This is my code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="SelectionListBox" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="130px" Width="350px">
<asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value ="1"  />
<asp:ListItem Text="Watermelon" Value ="2"  />
<asp:ListItem Text="Kiwi" Value ="3"  />
<asp:ListItem Text="Plum" Value ="4"  />
<asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value ="5"  />
```

```
<asp:Button ID="RetrieveButton" runat="server" Height="40px" Text="Retrieve" Width="130px" OnClick="RETRIEVE_BUTTON_Click" style="font-weight:bold" BackColor="#333333" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Groove" ForeColor="White" ViewStateMode="Inherit" />

    <asp:GridView ID="SelectionGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CellPadding="6" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" EmptyDataText="Record Not Found" OnRowDataBound ="SelectionGridView_OnRowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <columns>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"></asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Customer_ID" HeaderText="Customer ID"></asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Customer_Name" HeaderText="Customer Name"></asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age"></asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product"></asp:boundfield>         
        </columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>

   <div>
         <asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:scriptmanager>
    </div>
    <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <contenttemplate>

    <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>
        </contenttemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
```

-

```
protected void RETRIEVE_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
        container.ID = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
        container.EnableViewState = false;
        container.Tabs.Clear();
        container.Height = Unit.Pixel(500);
        container.Width = Unit.Pixel(1200);
        container.Tabs.AddAt(0, GetManualTab());

        foreach (ListItem item in SelectionListBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                Label tabContent = new Label();
                tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_";
                tabContent.Text += item.Value;

                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
                container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
            }
        }
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
    }

    public AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel GetManualTab()
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
        return panel;
    }
```

Appreciate if anyone could provide me help on this, thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need 2 things:

1. Get Tab header text:

```cs
foreach(Control control in Tabs.TabContainer1) {
            TabPanel tab = (TabPanel)control;
            string headerText = tab.HeaderText;
        }
```

2. Get GridView row text inside column:

```cs
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < GridView1.Rows.Count; currentRow++)
{
    string cellText = GridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[targetColumn].Text;
}
```

Then you simply match **headerText** with **cellText** and do something based on this comparison.